# Stop tracking Crashlytics runtime in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crashlytics

I've just integrated [Crashlytics with iOS](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics?utm_campaign=crashlytics-marketing&utm_medium=natural) and it's quite easy integration steps. I started session of crashlytics in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` with code `[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];` and its start tracking.

At some point in App I want to stop tracking of Crashlytics so how Can I do this? Is there any code for this? There is a way to stop tracking from online Dashboard in Crashlytics but I want to do from Code.

Looking for suggestions and help.
Thanks.

Comment: check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39390279/how-to-disable-crashlytics-for-ios-during-a-runtime

Answer (score 2):

Xcode debugger does NOT allow Crashlytics to process crash reports.

if you have your device connected to your Mac, XCode's debugger will step in as well. So just disconnect the device before testing.

```
To make sure a crash is reported during your simulator testing:
Launch simulator
Press stop
Launch your app and force a crash
Relaunch the app from simulator
See the crash report in the web dashboard
```

[Reference](https://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92523-why-can-t-i-have-xcode-connected-)

Comment: Thanks @KKRocks for answering but I think this is not my questions answer, My question simple is that how to stop tracking crashlytics at some part of app via coding ?

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Fabric here. I believe you're looking to kill an active Fabric session once it's been started with the same launch/session of the app.

In that case, there is not a way to kill the SDK session. I'd recommend wrapping the Fabric init in a conditional call or boolean check to see if Fabric should be initialized or not.

Comment: Thanks Mike for clarification, Yes this is also a way to start session in some condition.